# saving group checkbox and option values

Tags: php, checkbox

i have many check boxes all named features, with different values, how do i collect their values in php and whats the best method to save an repopulate the form when its loaded, so tha it will show previously selected values.

thanks

Comment: Checkboxes need unique names because each is a distinct true/false value.  Only radios can share names, because radios are "one of several".

Comment: @banzaimonkey — rubbish. Checkboxes do not have a true/false value, they have an author defined value and are either successful (in which case they are submitted) if checked (or not, if not). You can easily have a group of checkboxes with the same name, and loop over them to see what the values are.

Comment: @David Dorward This has been bugging me all night.  The way PHP handles POST is by constructing an array where **name** is the **key** and **value** is the **value**.  So if you have multiple checkboxes with the same name, only the last one will stick because any subsequent key with the same name will replace the preceding one.  So my original comment is correct, to the extent that "true/false" is understood as a boolean and not explicit "true" and "false" values.  Either a named checkbox `isset() == true` or `isset() == false`.  DOM != what PHP gets from headers.

Comment: That is PHP being weird. Unlike most form processing libraries, it discards multiple values with the same name (except the last one) unless that name ends with the characters `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes are are generated like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck' value="1" /> Unchecked checkbox
<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck' value="1" checked /> Checked checkbox
```

So you will output them with a code similar to this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='<?=$checkName?>' <?=$checked?'checked':''?> value="1" /> <?=$checkLabel?>
```

To redisplay, you will need to prepare the appropriare variables, according to user's post. You could put all of them in an array, and cycle upon it to generate them all.

Some tricks with checkboxes:

1. Unchecked checkboxes are NOT posted, i.e. you won't find them at all in the post. This means you cannot just cycle over the checkboxes. You have to cycle upon your full set of possibilities, and check if that possibility is present (checked) or absent (unchecked). Or, you can unset all the possibilities in your model, and then check only those present in the post.
2. It is possible to group them together by using arrays, like this:

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='options[check1]' value="1" /> Unchecked checkbox
    <input type='checkbox' name='options[check2]' value="1" /> Unchecked checkbox
```

you will get an array called $_POST['options'] in your POST, with check1 and check2 as your keys.